# robust_connection from aio_pika not reconnecting

Tags: python, rabbitmq, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I have the following application with asyncio and iohttp. On start of the application I start the web interface (iohttp) and the aio_pika consumer. Everything works so far for me the only thing is that the robut connection does not try to reconnect. When I restart my rabbit docker image I get this log message:

```
[2019-11-21 14:05:13,069] INFO: Connection to amqp://guest:******@127.0.0.1/ closed. Reconnecting after 5 seconds.
```

But than I receive the following exception and it doesnt reconnect:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 804, in _read_ready__data_received
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghovat/.local/share/virtualenvs/zendesk-wrapper-BdIlfSJk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py", line 148, in reconnect
    await self.connect()
  File "/home/ghovat/.local/share/virtualenvs/zendesk-wrapper-BdIlfSJk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py", line 134, in connect
    await self.__cleanup_connection(e)
  File "/home/ghovat/.local/share/virtualenvs/zendesk-wrapper-BdIlfSJk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py", line 96, in __cleanup_connection
    self.connection.close(exc),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Should the robust connection not try to reconnect again? The problem with `connection reset by peer` seems to be the rabbit startup which needs couple of seconds.

This is how I start the application:

```
def loop_in_thread(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    connection = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(connection.close())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = setup_app()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop_in_thread, args=(loop,))
    t.start()
    web.run_app(app)
```

This is how my consumer looks like:

```
async def main(loop):
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
        "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
    )

    queue_name = "test_queue"

    print("jdklasjkl")

    async with connection:
        # Creating channel
        channel = await connection.channel()

        # Declaring queue
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(
            queue_name, auto_delete=False
        )

        async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
            async for message in queue_iter:
                async with message.process():
                    print(message.body)

                    if queue.name in message.body.decode():
                        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update version 6.4.1, this pr should fix this problem - https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/pull/267

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an explanation for the link you provided to improve your answer.

Comment: This link contains changes in aio-pika library, which resolve this question

Comment: Please consider reading the [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section here, particularly the section for providing *context* for links. Links to information can *change* or become stale, and it is important to capture the context and critical information from the link **directly** in the answer post to avoid this issue.